# Problema na criação de faturas ao usar o projecto do GitHub

Tags: c#

Depois de implementar as alterações mencionadas, consegui resolver os problemas dos restantes campos porém surgiu um novo problema. Após modificar o código para o seguinte...

```
private static InvoiceResource CreateSampleInvoice()
        {
            return new InvoiceResource
            {
                Company = "GRG",
                Customer = "ALCAD",
                Lines = new List<InvoiceLineResource>
                    {
                        new InvoiceLineResource
                        {
                            Item = "0001",
                            Quantity = 1,
                            Description = "Item 0003 custom description.",
                            Price = new MoneyResource { Value = 50 }
                        }
                    }
            };
        }
```

Surgiu-me este erro:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Tenho de adicionar o campo "Warehouse" manualmente no ficheiro "InvoiceLineResource.cs" e neste campo também?

Comment: @Fábio esses dados "Empresa" e "entidade" não estão correctos, é isso que ele está a dizer.

Comment: @Fábio, acabei d testar com o exemplo que estás a usar csharp-createinvoice-sample e consegui criar a fatura sem problema. Claro que tive de ajustar os meus dados da empresa e cliente para poder validar.

Comment: @SérgioSereno podia por favor fazer-me chegar onde foi buscar no próprio software jasmin, estes campos?

Comment: Os campos são a abreviatura (da empresa), o artigo (do artigo) e a entidade(do cliente).

Comment: @Fábio Isto é uma nova questão. Não deves alterar o conteudo de questões porque se não as respostas deixam de fazer sentido.

Comment: Repoe a questão original por favor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

para criar uma fatura via webapi numa aplicação de faturação tens de cumprir com alguns requisitos, a ver:

- Criar uma empresa (todas as transações estão no ambito de uma empresa)
- Criar a entidade para quem vai faturar e e mercadoria/serviço que vai faturar.
- Ter uma serie activa e valida.

**Para criar uma empresa.**

- Configuração | Geral | Empresas | Criar. O código que deres a empresa tens de associar á propriedade `Company`.

**Para a Entidade**

- Vendas | Clientes. O código que deres ao cliente tens de associar á propriedade `Customer`.

**Para a artigo**

- Vendas | Artigos de Venda. O código que deres ao cliente tens de associar á propriedade `Item`.

No meu caso.

```
private static InvoiceResource CreateSampleInvoice()
{
    return new InvoiceResource
    {
        Company = "default",
        Customer = "0001",
        Lines = new List<InvoiceLineResource>
            {
                new InvoiceLineResource
                {
                    Item = "0003",
                    Quantity = 2,
                    Description = "Item 0003 custom description.",
                    Price = new MoneyResource { Value = 50 }
                }
            }
    };
}
```